# How to change date format in R data frame and add to new column?

Tags: r, dataframe, date

Suppose I have the following data frame with dates from 2020:

```
date
2020-01-01T05:00:00+0000
2020-02-01T05:00:00+0000
2020-01-01T05:00:00+0000
2020-03-01T05:00:00+0000
```

The column is of `type character`.

I want to create a second column which will return.g. Jan-20, Feb-20, etc. I.e. the following:

```
date                       date_name
2020-01-01T05:00:00+0000   Jan-20
2020-02-01T05:00:00+0000   Feb-20
2020-01-01T05:00:00+0000   Jan-20
2020-03-01T05:00:00+0000   Mar-20
```

Note that e.g. `-01-` refers to January.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this. You only need year and month, so you can use `as.Date()` and `format()` to reach what you expect:

```
#Code
df$date_name <- format(as.Date(df$date),'%b-%Y')
```

Output:

```
df
                      date date_name
1 2020-01-01T05:00:00+0000  Jan-2020
2 2020-02-01T05:00:00+0000  Feb-2020
3 2020-01-01T05:00:00+0000  Jan-2020
4 2020-03-01T05:00:00+0000  Mar-2020
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(date = c("2020-01-01T05:00:00+0000", "2020-02-01T05:00:00+0000", 
"2020-01-01T05:00:00+0000", "2020-03-01T05:00:00+0000")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Many thanks :), also upvoted yours but I am not a big fan of data.table haha

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option (but the `format` approach by @Duck is more efficient)

```
> setDT(df)[, date_name := paste0(month.abb[month(date)], "-", substr(year(date), 3, 4))][]
                       date date_name
1: 2020-01-01T05:00:00+0000    Jan-20
2: 2020-02-01T05:00:00+0000    Feb-20
3: 2020-01-01T05:00:00+0000    Jan-20
4: 2020-03-01T05:00:00+0000    Mar-20
```

Comment: nice approach using `data.table`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `as.yearmon` from `zoo`

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
df %>% 
    mutate(date_name = as.yearmon(date))
```

-output

```
#                      date date_name
#1 2020-01-01T05:00:00+0000  Jan 2020
#2 2020-02-01T05:00:00+0000  Feb 2020
#3 2020-01-01T05:00:00+0000  Jan 2020
#4 2020-03-01T05:00:00+0000  Mar 2020
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(date = c("2020-01-01T05:00:00+0000", "2020-02-01T05:00:00+0000", 
"2020-01-01T05:00:00+0000", "2020-03-01T05:00:00+0000")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```